# Getting data from three tables using join mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables in my database

1.Users (id,username)

2.Stories (id,user_id,content) here `user_id` is forigen key refers `Users` table `id`

3.Comments (id,user_id,story_id,comment)   here `user_id` is forigen key refers `Users` table `id` and `story_id` is forigen key refers `Stories` table `id`

I need to get list of stories from  `Stories` table with total number of comments on that post and username of the storie author

Here is my query for that

```
SELECT stories.id,stories.content,COUNT(stories.id) as totalcomment
FROM stories
 JOIN comments
ON stories.id=comments.story_id GROUP BY stories.id
```

I will get the total comment of the each post ,but can't fetch the username of the storie author (ie username from Users table)

Comment: What is stopping you from joining `Users` table?

Comment: The same way, you've joined comments

Comment: Have you maintained relation of users table with comments or stories?

Comment: Yes i maintained with both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT stories.id,stories.content,COUNT(stories.id) as totalcomment, Users.username
FROM stories, Users, comments
WHERE stories.id=comments.story_id
AND stories.user_id = Users.id
GROUP BY stories.id
```

Or with join:

```
SELECT stories.id,stories.content,COUNT(stories.id) as totalcomment, Users.username
FROM stories
JOIN comments ON stories.id=comments.story_id
JOIN users ON stories.user_id = Users.id
GROUP BY stories.id
```

Hope this works.

Comment: I will get the error messages unknown column but ccolumn is present\

Comment: This will return an indeterminate result.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.id,s.content,COUNT(c.story_id) as totalcomment, u.username
FROM stories s LEFT JOIN comments c ON (s.id=c.story_id)
LEFT JOIN users u ON (s.user_id = u.id)
GROUP BY s.id
```